# Can ethereum contract owner pay the gas of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Is it possible that the contract owner will pay the gas fees of every token transaction is being made in an ERC20 token contract?

I've searched for a solution online and couldn't find anything.

Comment: See [How to make someone else pay for Gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38479/how-to-make-someone-else-pay-for-gas) and [Can contracts pay the gas instead of the message sender?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Gas must be paid for by the account that initiates the transaction.